# Stubbed function always returns null

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Currently I'm following a tutorial of Resocoder (DDD Course). In this course there is an abstract class called [i_auth_facade.dart](https://github.com/ResoCoder/finished-flutter-firebase-ddd-course/blob/master/lib/domain/auth/i_auth_facade.dart), which contains a function getSignedInUser.

I have mocked the class and trying to get a valid option of user back from the getSignedInUser method, but the result is always null.

Also when I try to execute the [authCheckRequested](https://github.com/ResoCoder/finished-flutter-firebase-ddd-course/blob/master/lib/application/auth/auth_bloc.dart) method of the AuthBloc, which then in the background invokes the getSignedInUser method, I get back null.

I must have some error with Mockito, as it seems the stub doesn't work.

Can anybody point me into the right direction why I don't get back the optionOf(User), but null instead?

```
import 'package:bloc_test/bloc_test.dart';
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:teach_mob_student/application/auth/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:teach_mob_student/domain/auth/i_auth_facade.dart';
import 'package:teach_mob_student/domain/auth/user.dart';
import 'package:teach_mob_student/domain/auth/value_objects.dart';
import 'package:teach_mob_student/domain/core/value_objects.dart';

class MockIAuthFacade extends Mock implements IAuthFacade {}

void main() {
  final tValidUser = User(
    id: UniqueId(),
    name: StringSingleLine('Test User'),
    emailAddress: EmailAddress('test@user.com'));


  test('Should return valid option of user', () async {
    // This is to check, if optionOf actually returns a user --> Yes it does
    Option<User> tDirectResult = optionOf<User>(tValidUser);

    // Here I stub the getSignedInUser method. If it is executed, I want to receive a valid user.
    when(MockIAuthFacade()
      .getSignedInUser()
    ).thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value(optionOf<User>(tValidUser)));

    // Here I execute the method, and I would expect to get Future<Option<User>> back, but I only get back null.
    final facade = MockIAuthFacade();

    Option<User> tStubbedResult = await facade.getSignedInUser();

    print(tDirectResult);
    print(tStubbedResult);
  });

  // Here I do the same, but I execute the authCheckRequested method of the AuthBloc, which executes the
  // getSignedInUser method. Also here I get back null as result.
  blocTest('Should return valid option of user.', 
    build: () async {
      when(MockIAuthFacade()
        .getSignedInUser()
      ).thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value(optionOf<User>(tValidUser)));

      return AuthBloc(MockIAuthFacade());
    },
    act: (bloc) async {
      bloc.add(AuthEvent.authCheckRequested());
    },
    expect: [
    ]
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?